# How to iterate over a dictionary of arrays in Angular component?

Tags: angular

I (think) I have a dictionary data set with the keys being a date and the value being at least one array

```
private dateArray = {};
```

I am dynamically loading more arrays to the dictionary array so that I can show them as different sections on the component. The goal is something like this:

**Date Joined: 9/1/17**

Name: Mary, Age: 40

Name: John, Age: 20

**Date Joined: 10/1/17**

Name: Jeff, Age: 30

`dateArray` ends up having the date as a string in the key and then the properties are added as multiple arrays of their specific properties.

```
{Fri Sept 1 2017: ([Name: Mary, Age: 40],[Name: John, Age: 20]),
Sun Oct 1 2017: [Name: Jeff, Age: 30]}
```

How do I access the data from the template side? I am using Angular 2. I tried the [Mapping Object Keys section](https://webcake.co/object-properties-in-angular-2s-ngfor/) and did not have any luck getting anything to display. Is piping the best route in Angular 2?

Comment: I would argue that 'private dateArray = {};' is not a good name for this variable/object. When you declare this variable with {}, you are not creatring an array. You better use another name, so it would have a better meaning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can create a property with the keys, iterate over them and then get the array for each key (as long as you can only use ngFor with an iterable, and an json-like/hash object, as this {}, is not iterable).

.ts

```
this.keys = Object.keys(dateDictionary)
```

.html

```
<div *ngFor="let key of keys">
  <div *ngFor="let date of dateDictionary[key]">
    <p>{{ date.date }}</p>
    <p>{{ date.Name }}</p>
    <p>{{ date.Age }}</p>
  </div>  
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to declare `dateArray` as public. The template access only the `public` members.

After that you can do in the template something like this:

```
<div *ngFor="let date of dateArray">
  <p>{{ date.date }}</p>
  <p>{{ date.Name }}</p>
  <p>{{ date.Age }}</p>
</div>
```

Hint: the `dateArray` array should be like this:

```
[
  {
    "date": "Fri Sept 1 2017",
    "Name": "test1",
    "Age": "12"
  },
  {
    "date": "Fri Sept 1 2017",
    "Name": "test2",
    "Age": "2"
  }
]
```

Comment: The reason that I set it up like a dictionary is so that the items could be grouped by the same date. Should the grouping occur in the template?

Comment: @cooper the less login in the template, the better (in most cases, of courses).